# Passing the intent string extra from my FragmentActivity to my Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm doing something that needs to send the ID of the selected item to a fragment contained on one of my Layout. I do know the basic of fragment but I don't know how to properly communicate from Activity to Fragment. Well here's my code for now:

```
    public class GroupActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    Button information, back;
    TextView group_name;
    String name, group_description, group_administrator,image_id;
    public static String group_id;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.group_screen);
        Intent intent = getIntent();

        name = intent.getStringExtra("group_name");
        group_description = intent.getStringExtra("group_description");
        group_administrator = intent.getStringExtra("group_administrator");
        image_id = intent.getStringExtra("image_id");
        group_id = intent.getStringExtra("group_id");

        information = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_information);
        back = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_back);
        group_name = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt_group_name);

        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"The group id "+group_id,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


        group_name.setText(name);

        information.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(GroupActivity.this, GroupInformationActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("group_name",name);
                intent.putExtra("group_description",group_description);
                intent.putExtra("group_administrator",group_administrator);
                intent.putExtra("image_id",image_id);
                startActivity(intent);
                GroupActivity.this.overridePendingTransition(R.anim.in_from_left, R.anim.out_to_right);
            }
        });

        back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                onBackPressed();
            }
        });
    }



    private void showCreateNewTopicDialog() {
        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        DialogNewTopic newTopic = new DialogNewTopic();
        newTopic.show(fm, "new_topic");
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed(){
        super.onBackPressed();
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.in_from_right,R.anim.out_to_left);
    }

}
```

and the Fragment

```
public class GroupConversationsFragment extends ListFragment {

    final ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> list = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();

    String[][] conversation_header = {{"0","Topic 1","10/03/2013 10:21:am","2","0"},{"0","Topic 2","10/04/2013 1:29:pm","5","0"}};
    String group_id;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        setConversations();
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.conversations_list_view, container, false);
    }


    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), ConversationActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        getActivity().overridePendingTransition(R.anim.in_from_left, R.anim.out_to_right);
    }

    private void setConversations(){
        list.clear();
        SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                getActivity(),
                list,
                R.layout.custom_list_main_conversations,
                new String[] {"message","date", "reply_count", "stars_count"},
                new int[] {R.id.txt_conversation_message,R.id.txt_topic_date, R.id.txt_no_of_reply, R.id.txt_no_of_stars}
        );

        for(int ctr=0; ctr < conversation_header.length; ctr++){
            Log.v("The header group id", conversation_header[ctr][0]);

            if(conversation_header[ctr][0].equals(group_id)){
                HashMap<String,String> item_list = new HashMap<String,String>();
                item_list.put("message", conversation_header[ctr][1]);
                item_list.put("date", conversation_header[ctr][2]);
                item_list.put("reply_count", conversation_header[ctr][3]);
                item_list.put("stars_count", conversation_header[ctr][4]);
                list.add(item_list);
            }
        }


        setListAdapter(adapter);
    }

}
```

and to explain it further what I do in here is that the activity gets the stringExtra from the Activity before it then set it on a variable. Now this activity has it's own layout which contains the Listfragment since I'm using a custom list. I then need to pass the group_id to the fragment to display the proper topic based on the group_id. What I tried so far is to use a static String variable from Activity and access it on my Fragment but I think there is an issue on the Fragment Lifecycle which doesn't set the id properly. Hope someone can give me a straight to the point answer on how I can achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You can create an `Activity` that extends a base activity and access the required method or field of the activity in the fragment.
- You can go for Broadcast Receiver.
- You can send data from the `Activity` through the intent as:

  ```
  Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
  bundle.putString("key","value - from the activity");

  GroupConversationsFragment fragmentObject = new GroupConversationsFragment();
  fragmentObject.setArguments(bundle);

      -> in GroupConversationsFragment onCreateView():

  @Override
      public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
          Bundle savedInstanceState) {

              String val = getArguments.getString("key");

              return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, container, false);
          }
  ```

Comment: Hi @Niveditha, I tried the Bundle adding of string but I'm getting a null pointer exception on the part of String val = getArguments().getString("key");

Comment: Try doing this; Bundle bundle = new Bundle(); GroupConversationsFragment fragmentObject = new GroupConversationsFragment();bundle.putString("key","value - from the activity");

fragmentObject.setArguments(bundle); See how you are replacing the fragment